# Returning the Sum of 2 Dimensional Array elements from DLL C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dll

I am trying to return the sum of the elements of a 2 dimensional array from my DLL, but can't seem to get it to work correctly.  The returning integer which should be the 'sum' of the array elements returns a null.  Could use some advice...

```
                int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };

                Class1.arraySum(array2D);
                Console.WriteLine("Sum of 2D Array of numbers ({ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 })\n");
                Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

DLL

```
public static int arraySum(int[,] values)
    {
        int sum = values.Cast<int>().Sum();
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare and *fill* the `sum` variable

```
        int sum = Class1.arraySum(array2D);
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of 2D Array of numbers ({ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 })\n");
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

or write it down "on the fly":

```
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of 2D Array of numbers ({ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 })\n");
        Console.WriteLine(Class1.arraySum(array2D));
```

Comment: So that doesn't send it to my DLL however.  I want to have my DLL perform the sum method and then return the value

Comment: I missed the `Class1` reference I took off for my test, see edited answer.

Comment: BTW you could reduce your `arraySum()` method body to one line `return values.Cast<int>().Sum(); `